# Javascript object's methods properties

Tags: javascript, oop

```
var someVar = anObjectInstance.someMethod({
                  anArray : [
                               { "key" : "value" },
                               { "key" : "value" } 
                            ]
              });
```

In the above code how do I access the `anArray[1]` of `anObjectInstance` using the variable `someVar`

Comment: -1 What is `someProperty`?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?..

Comment: it was not somePropert, but someMehtod

Answer (score 1):

This is language basics.

There is no single answer for your question.

Let's take a look at two different situations:

#### 1

```
function A(){}

A.prototype.m = function(data){ console.log(data) };

var ai = new A();

var b = ai.m({ a : [ { k1 : 'V1', k2 : 'V2' } ] });
```

`m` will returns undefined, so the value of `b` variable is `undefined`. By using of this `b` variable you cannot access to anything.

#### 2

```
function A(){}

A.prototype.m = function(data){ return data; };

var ai = new A();

var b = ai.m({ a : [ { k1 : 'V1', k2 : 'V2' } ] });
```

In the second example the `m` methods returns first argument value, so you can get an access to it by using `b` variable.

```
console.log(b.a[0].k1);//returns `V1`
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few mistakes in your code right now.

You try to declare object property before you create object instance, e. g. using `{}`

```
var anObjectInstance = {};
```

You try to create some method (function) in `someMethod`, but your syntax is wrong. I can't totally understand what exactly you want to achieve with this method, but there proper declaration should be like this:

```
anObjectInstance.someMethod= function(){
    var someVar = [{'foo':'bar'}];
    return someVar;

};
```

Now you can access someVar array using `someMethod`:

```
console.log( anObjectInstance.someMethod() );
```

Comment: I did edit the question. Please look now. someProperty was by mistake. Now it is someMethod()